# Angular 4: One Subscription, Two Http Calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am attempting to post data to the server in a very standard manner that I have probably done a million times before, however in this particular case two http calls are being made.  Can anyone help explain why this may happen?

I am using Angular 4.2.4 with Rxjs 5.4.3 and posting to the server using and instance of `HttpClient`.

Below is the relevant component code, being called using an event handler from the UI.

```
this.visitsService
    .addMeasuredWeight(this.visit.Id, this.kid.Id, weight)
    .subscribe(result =>
      this.kid.Weights.push(MeasuredWeightDto.ToMeasuredWeight(result))
    );
```

And this is the service code

```
    public addMeasuredWeight(
          visitId: string,
          personId: string,
          measuredWeight: MeasuredWeight
    ): Observable<MeasuredWeightDto> {
      let url: string = `${this.getBaseUrl()}/${visitId}/persons/${personId}/weights`;

      return this.http.post<MeasuredWeightDto>(
        url,
        MeasuredWeightDto.FromMeasuredWeight(measuredWeight)
      );
    }
```

I have confirmed through the debugger that these methods are only being called once, however in the Chrome DevTools network tab, two http posts are made and indeed the subscription result handler runs twice.  Below is a screen shot from DevTools showing the multiple posts.

[image]

Any help determining why multiple calls are made here will be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if any additional information is required. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a line with nothing but `debugger;` to the method body and open up the dev console. It will probably break here twice.

Comment: is it a preflight request that is being sent by the browser to check can confirm

Comment: @Igor It does not break twice.  I already tried with standard breakpoints but also just tried `debugger;` to make sure

Comment: @RahulSingh It is not a preflight.  Preflight requests use the `Options` http verb.  Both of these requests are `Post`.

Comment: Are there any other services that might be calling the same end point in your app? Maybe a copy/paste by mistake or something?

Comment: @Igor This is the only service that calls this particular endpoint.  I have confirmed by using a workspace wide search on /weights.  Only 3 results, one each for Http `get`, `post`, and `put`.  Since both calls are `post` they must be going through the same method.  Additionally, I can confirm that the result handler specified in the component code above is being called twice.

Comment: so you are telling that the debugger also shows it is called only once , can you confirm it not being caused by a malfunctioning Observable

Comment: @RahulSingh That is correct, the debugger shows it is only being called once.  As for the malfunctioning Observable, not sure how to check that but if you can explain it to me I will be happy to give it a try.